# Running Tasks in different thread in Spring Webflux Annotated controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a spring Webflux Annotated controller as below,

```
 @RestController
public class TestBlockingController {

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

  @GetMapping()
  public Mono<String> blockForXSeconds(@RequestParam("block-seconds") Integer blockSeconds) {
    return getStringMono();
  }

  private Mono<String> getStringMono() {
    Integer blockSeconds = 5;
    String type = new String();
    try {
      if (blockSeconds % 2 == 0) {
        Thread.sleep(blockSeconds * 1000);
        type = "EVEN";
      } else {
        Thread.sleep(blockSeconds * 1000);
        type = "ODD";
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Got Exception");
    }
    log.info("Type of block-seconds: " + blockSeconds);
    return Mono.just(type);
  }
}
```

How do I make getStringMono run in a different thread than Netty server threads. The problem I am facing is that as I am running in server thread I am getting basically less throughput (2 requests per second). How do I go about making running getStringMono in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subscribeOn`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) operator to delegate the task to a different threadpool:

```java
Mono.defer(() -> getStringMono()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

Although, you have to note that this type of blocking should be avoided in a reactive application at any cost. If possible, use a client which supports non-blocking IO and returns a promise type (Mono, CompletableFuture, etc.). If you just want to have an artificial delay, then use [`Mono.delay`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#delay-java.time.Duration-) instead.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mono.defer() method.
The method signature is as:

```
public static <T> Mono<T> defer(Supplier<? extends Mono<? extends T>> supplier)
```

Your Rest API should look like this.

```
@GetMapping()
public Mono<String> blockForXSeconds(@RequestParam("block-seconds") Integer blockSeconds) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> getStringMono());
}
```

The [defer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) operator is there to make this source lazy, re-evaluating the content of the lambda each time there is a new subscriber. This will increase your API throughput.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955567/what-does-mono-defer-do) you can view the detailed analysis.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps.

Comment: without explicilty specified scheduler, this code will continue to work on the same  thread. `subsribeOn`/`publishOn` is required.

Comment: Thank you sir. Continue to suggest me if I am wrong. This will definitely increase my knowledge.