# Using Spring Reactor Mono with multiple switchIfEmpty

Tags: java, method-chaining, spring-reactor

I had a simple java validation flow like this example:

```java
if (!request.isValid()) {
    throw new ValidationException("Its not valid");
}

if (!request.isCorrect()) {
    throw new IncorrectException();
}

return Mono.just(
        someService.process(request)
);
```

I tried to chain method calls to get rid of `ifs` but this does not work:

```java
return Mono.just(request)
        .filter(req -> !req.isValid())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ValidationException("Its not valid")))
        .filter(req -> !req.isCorrect())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IncorrectException()))
        .flatMap(req -> Mono.just(someService.process(req)));
```

The problem is, even if it fails on `isValid()` the code goes on and the second `switch` overwrites the first one.

How could I make the code working and retain the chaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use "Mono.defer()"?

Your code would be something like:

```
return Mono.just(request)
            .filter(req -> !req.isValid())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new ValidationException("Its not valid"))))
            .filter(req -> !req.isCorrect())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new IncorrectException())))
            .flatMap(req -> Mono.just(someService.process(req)));
```

I had the same issue, and it worked for me.

You can read more about Mono.defer() on this thread:

[what does Mono.defer() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955567/what-does-mono-defer-do)

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know about that, seems a good way, will try it shortly

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because the filters should be the opposite. You specify what passes, not what filtered out:

```
    return Mono.just(request)
    // lets through valid request only:
    .filter(req -> req.isValid()) 
    // if it was invalid, its empty, thus switches to error:
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ValidationException("Its not valid"))) 
    // filters out which is not correct:
    .filter(req -> req.isCorrect())
    // if not correct, its empty, switch to error:
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IncorrectException())) 
    .flatMap(req -> Mono.just(someService.process(req)));
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I think that the problem was that if both of filter method removed the value, the second exception was returned instead of first one. But it was long ago :)