# Mono.switchIfEmpty with Mono.then evaluation order

Tags: mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I build the reactive pipeline like this on netty server with spring web-flux:

```
someService.getSettings(key) //Mono<Settings>
        .filter(Settings::isEnabled)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
            new Exception("Setting is disabled.")
        )).then(/*Mono representing API fetch*/ someApi.fetch(param));
```

As per my understanding, whenever the `Settings::isEnabled` would return false, the pipeline would be empty and I will get a Mono representing error. However, this behavior does not happens. My `someApi.fetch(param)` call always fires without the filter Mono being completed. So even if `Settings::isEnabled` is false or true, `someApi.fetch(param)` is always fired without completion of `Mono.filter`.

How do I make sure that error is thrown if filter returns empty Mono and the fetch call happens only when I have checked that the setting is not disabled?

Comment: your issue is very similar to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870706/whats-the-point-of-switchifempty-getting-evaluated-eagerly/57877616#57877616 except, in your case then is evaluated eagerly instead of switchIfEmpty

Comment: What do you want to achieve by calling to someApi.fetch(param)? Does it return something? You may want to do something like .switchIfEmpty(...).flatMap(settings -> someApi.fetch(settings.getParam()))

Comment: someApi.fetch(param) is always fired because .then(mono) ignores the previous Mono and returns the mono from the parameter. From docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-
Let this Mono complete then play another Mono.
In other words ignore element from this Mono and transform its completion signal into the emission and completion signal of a provided Mono<V>.

Answer (score 1):

this is still java: this call to `someApi.fetch(param)` is not done inside a lambda, so it can't be lazy. the moment the execution reaches the `then` line, your `fetch` method is called. the `Flux.defer` operator is tailor-made to wrap that call and make it lazy.