# Mono::then returns null

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm relatively new to reactive programming.
My question is regarding `Mono::then`

What I want to do is, extract the body from incoming request, set it to a static variable.
Once that is done, send a response saying that the service has started.
But the following code always returns "Service started for: null".

I thought `Mono::then` should run after the first mono completes(in this case, after setting the static variable) and return "Service started for: a,b,c".

Is my understanding wrong?

(Also, any code criticism is appreciated)

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getStatus(ServerRequest req) {
        Mono<List<Request>> body = req.bodyToFlux(Request.class).collectList();
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .body(body.doOnNext(i -> {
                    Service.a = i;
                    logger.info("Service started for : {}", i.toString());
                })


                        .then(Mono.just("Service started for: " + Service.a)), String.class);
    }
```

Comment: "Mono::then should run after" There is nothing to run.
Mono::just javadoc:
"Create a new Mono that emits the specified item, which is captured at instantiation time."
You can check your assumptions about Mono::then using Mono::fromCallable, Mono::fromSupplier instead of Mono::just

Comment: Shouldn't Mono::just run "after" body.doOnNext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communicating through static variables are very discouraged (especially in functional and reactive programming). As in your question you didn't provide enough information about the `Service` you start, it's a bit difficult to recommend.

However, based on the available information, I would start out with something like this:

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> getStatus(ServerRequest req) {
    return req.bodyToFlux(Request.class)
            .collectList()
            .doOnNext(requestBody -> System.out.println("Do your service start here in the background."))
            .flatMap(requestBody -> ServerResponse.ok().syncBody("Service started for: " + requestBody));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the response. I've since made changes and no longer use static variables.I was wondering why `Mono::then` wasn't working as expected.
My understanding is that it should wait till the previous Mono ends and then emit the mono in then().

Comment: It is because the string inside is getting evaluated eagerly before the first part of the flow is executed, details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877616/6051176 As another commenter suggested, you can use Mono::fromSupplier to overcome this issue.

Comment: **It is because the string inside is getting evaluated eagerly before the first part of the flow is executed** makes sense.
Thank you for the explanation. Can consider this as closed.