# Reactive repository only works with block()

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Spring boot application. As part of it, I should keep track of a simple object ActiveVersion that has two fields, type and version. I persist this object in both redis and mongo. ActiveVersionCacheRepository is a reactive redis repository (using reactiveRedisTemplate) and ActiveVersionRepository is a reactive mongo repository.
This is part of ActiveVersionService. Methods to retrieve and persist the activeVersion:

```kotlin
fun getActiveVersion(type: String): Mono<ActiveVersion> {
        return activeVersionCacheRepository.findByKey(type)
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer{activeVersionRepository.findByType(type)}
                ).switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer{persist(ActiveVersion(type,1))}
                )
    }

fun persist(activeVersion: ActiveVersion): Mono<ActiveVersion> {
    activeVersionCacheRepository.save(activeVersion.type, activeVersion)
    return activeVersionRepository.save(activeVersion)
}
```

This is my test method:

```kotlin
@Test
fun getNewActiveVersion(){
    var activeVersion = activeVersionService.getActiveVersion("newDummy").block()
    assertEquals(activeVersion?.version,1)
}
```

My problem is when I debug the test method and go step by step in ide and evaluate persist lines with block method such as: `activeVersionCacheRepository.save(activeVersion.type, activeVersion).block()` the active version indeed gets persisted in redis. But when I just go through the code without evaluating with block (or simply by running the test not debugging) nothing gets saved in redis. I am new to reactive programming so maybe I am missing something in switchIfEmpty or somewhere else.

Comment: First rule of reactive streams: nothing happens until you subscribe. So to trigger the execution you need subscribe/block.

Comment: I called block() in my test method. Wondering why it doesn't work, as I expect at least

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877616/6051176

Comment: Yes, indeed the link in the comment above was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was me getting the paradigm wrong. The problem was with my persist method. I changed it to this and it worked:

```kotlin
fun persist(activeVersion: ActiveVersion): Mono<ActiveVersion> {
    return activeVersionCacheRepository.save(activeVersion.type, activeVersion).then(
        activeVersionRepository.save(activeVersion)
    )
}
```