# How can catch MonoError?

Tags: java, try-catch, spring-webflux, flux, reactor

I need to catch MonoError and stop an application with ErrorResponse, but the application works as I did not expect.

My code:

```
return checkText(text)
                .then(getWordsFromText(text))
                .map(keyWords -> new SuccessfulResponse(keyWords))
                .onErrorResume(
                        throwable -> {
                            return Mono.just(new ErrorResponse(throwable.getMessage()));
                        });

public Mono<Void> checkText(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("wrong text"));
        } 
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

my problem is that if **text** param is **null** -> I fall into **getWordsFromText** method. This is an incorrect execution, because if the **text** parameter is equal to **null**, then the application must exit with an error (with ErrorResponse).

I fixed it as (replacing **'then'** to **'flatMap'**):

```
return checkText(text)
                .flatMap(voidParam -> getWordsFromText(text)) //replaced 'then' to 'flatMap'
                .map(keyWords -> new SuccessfulResponse(keyWords))
                .onErrorResume(
                        throwable -> {
                            return Mono.just(new ErrorResponse(throwable.getMessage()));
                        });
```

and now it's working correctly. If **text** param is **null** I miss the call **getWordsFromText** method and fall in error handling (**onErrorResume**).

But I think using flatMap in my case is not a good idea, I don't like how it looks: *.flatMap(voidParam -> ...*

Can you have any ideas how possible to do better? (without 'flatMap')

Comment: I recommend checking this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870706/whats-the-point-of-switchifempty-getting-evaluated-eagerly/57877616#57877616

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, the call to `getWordsFromText()` is made while building your main reactive pipeline, before it is even subscribed to (i.e. at assembly time). The reason it works as intended in the second snippet is that `flatMap` only creates the inner publishers (and subsequently subscribes to them) as it receives elements from upstream (i.e. at subscription time).

In this case if you want to replace the `flatMap` you could try this: `.then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> getWordsFromText(text)))`