# How to get an element that caused an exception in Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Let's say I have an array of ids: `[9, 8, 7, 6]`.

I do some processing and one element causes to throw an exception. I want to handle this situation on my own way (let's say log it) and let the other elements go with the flow.

How can I know which one was it? I need to have this element in my `onError` processing.

```
Flux.fromArray(myArray)
  .flatMap(element -> {
    var foo = processMyEl(element);  
    return anotherProcess(foo); // this returns Mono
  })
  .onErrorOperator(element -> handleMyError(element)) // this line is what I need
```

So, what I saw, there's this almost nice `.onErrorContinue((error, obj) ->` that emits an error and an object.

But this `obj` is not the `element` that caused the exception but the object that did so. It happens inside of my processing methods and it doesn't have to be the same type of object every time.

`.onErrorReturn(...)` - not really what I want

`.doOnError(error ->` - no information of my element

`.onErrorResume(error ->` - same as above

there were suggestions that I can create my own Exception and pass there the element and then retrieve it from the exception. But how should I throw the exception?

Should I go with an old way of try catch:

```
Flux.fromArray(myArray)
  .flatMap(el -> {
    try {
      var foo = processMyEl(el);  
      return anotherProcess(foo); // this returns Mono
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return Mono.error(new MyException(el));
     }
    })
  .onErrorOperator(error -> handleMyError(error.getElement()))
```

It doesn't look well

**Edit:**

Not only it looks bad, but also doesn't work. The exception is not caught at all and triggers directly `doOnTerminate()` and stops the whole stream

**Update:**

Thanks to @JEY I used `.onErrorResume()` inside `flatMap`.

I also transformed first method to be a reactive stream by `Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(processMyEl(el)))`.

Just as a note: using `Mono.defer()` allows me to use `onErrorResume` since `Mono.just()` [cannot signal errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56116772/1873995)

Final code looks like this:

```
Flux.fromArray(myArray)
    .flatMap(element -> Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(processMyEl(element)))
        .onErrorResume(th -> handleMyError(element, th))
    )
    .flatMap(foo -> anotherProcess(foo)
        .onErrorResume(th -> handleMyError(foo, th)
    )
```

Where:

```
private Mono<> handleMyError(el, th) {
  // handling code
  return Mono.empty()
}
```

Comment: You should go with you old try-catch but don't return Mono of error handle your error and return Mono.empty() so that your error won't be seen down stream and flux will keep getting consume.

Comment: yeah, I tried to have my logic in catch clause but the code doesn't even reach there, just terminates my stream and that's all

Comment: if it doesn't reach it, it means that the error is thrown somewhere else. Without more info we won't be able to help.

Comment: no, it's being thrown inside one of those two methods, but since one method returns `Mono` - as I mentioned in the question, and the exception can be thrown there, it's not going to be caught by try catch since it's not in its scope anymore

Comment: don't use a try-catch then but a anotherProcess.onErrorResume(th -> { LOG.error("error", th); return Mono.emtpy();})

Comment: and how can I get my element there?

Comment: You have direct access to it anotherProcess.onErrorResume(th -> { LOG.error("error with element", element, th); return Mono.emtpy();}) or anotherProcess.onErrorResume(th -> { LOG.error("error with element", element, th); return handleMyError(element).then();})

Comment: you're right! what I also did was to get rid of try catch entirely and transform to reactive stream by `Mono.just(processMyEl(el))` and then apply `onErrorResume` like you suggested to both of them, feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it; I'll also post my final code

Comment: alright then glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by @Kamil I'll add my comments as an answer:

You should just handle the error in the flatMap and return a Mono.empty() to discard it do something like:

```java
Flux.fromArray(myArray)
  .flatMap(el -> anotherProcess(processMyEl(el)).onErrorResume(th -> handleError(th, el))
```

With handle error like:

```java
Mono<Void> handleError(Throwable th, Object element) {
    LOG.error("An error occurred on {}", element, th);
    return Mono.empty()
}
```

Or if you want to do something more complex that require async:

```java
Mono<Void> handleError(Throwable th, Object element) {
    return doSomethingThaReturnFluxOrMono(element).then();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MyException(el, e);
}
```

Comment: I cannot throw an exception in catch clause in a flatMap, having `return Mono.error(new MyException(el))` or `return Flux.error(new MyException(el))` is the right way to signal an exception down the stream