# Repeat WebClient call with incremented query parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-webclient

i am trying to build one method that should do many HTTP requests to one external endpoint while one query parameter is less than 45000.

I need to do that because the external endpoint allow me to get 100 items but there are more than 44000 items to get.

```java
private int offset = 0;

public Flux<List<Model>> getItems() {
    return Flux.from(
            webClientBuilder
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("/getItems")
                            .queryParam("limit", 100)
                            .queryParam("offset", getOffset())
                            .build())
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Model.class)
                    .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
                    .flatMap(model -> {
                        setOffset(getOffset() + 100);
                        log.info("Offset: " + getOffset());
                        return repository.saveAll(model.getData().getResults()).collectList();
                    }).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(15)))
                    .repeat(() -> getOffset() <= 45000);
}

public int getOffset() {
    return offset;
}

public void setOffset(int offset) {
    this.offset = offset;
}
```

It seems to work because logs the offset parameter incremented but HTTP requests has offset equals to 0. the method returns first 100 items instead of 44566 items

Comment: Im only guessing, but repeat i think repeats the subscribe to the flux fetched from webclient. Dont think it repeats the entire call. I would do a recursive aproach calling the method again in the doOnSuccess

Comment: It can be good idea, i will test it too, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in fact, that `webclient` is built eagerly before subscription, and "cached", with initial `offset` value . After each call, `Flux` is resubscribed, but prepared webservice call with offset remains "cached". 
You must provide `weblient` in lazy way (for example by wrapping it in lambda), which forces all its parameters to recalculate for each call. There is special operator for that - `defer()`.

**Solution**:

```
Mono<Model> response = Mono.defer(() -> webClientBuilder
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/getItems")
                .queryParam("limit", 100)
                .queryParam("offset", getOffset())
                .build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Model.class)
);


Flux.from(response
        .doOnEach(System.out::println)
        .flatMap(model -> {
            setOffset(getOffset() + 100);
            log.info("Offset: " + getOffset());
            return repository.saveAll(model.getData().getResults()).collectList();
        }).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
).repeat(() -> getOffset() <= 45000).subscribe();
```

Another question which demonstrates identical problem with eager execution:
[Mono switchIfEmpty() is always called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373920/mono-switchifempty-is-always-called)

Comment: Thank for answer, it works great and is exactly what i want to do. **Thanks**