# Unable to load value from Redis alone even if value is present

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis, spring-reactive

I am using Reactive Redis where I am trying to use Redis as cache for database. I am checking if value is present in the cache or not? If it is present then return it otherwise query database if result comes back; store the result cache it and return it.

However, even if value is present in Redis it is still querying the database all the time.

```
public Mono<User> getUser(String email) {
    return reactiveRedisOperation.opsForValue().get("tango").switchIfEmpty(
        // Always getting into this block (for breakpoint) :(
        queryDatabase().flatMap(it -> {
            reactiveRedisOperation.opsForValue().set("tango", it, Duration.ofSeconds(3600)).then(Mono.just(it)); 
        })
    );
}

private Mono<User> queryDatabase() {
    return Mono.just(new User(2L,"test","test","test","test","test",true,"test","test","test"));
}
```

But call is always hitting the database even if value is present in Redis. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try to extract this `reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue()` to variable and use in those two places?

Comment: Can you show me an example since I am using Mono here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54412779/11733759) you can try with `Mono.defer`:

```java
public Mono<User> getUser(String email) {
    return reactiveRedisOperation.opsForValue().get("tango").switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
        // Always getting into this block (for breakpoint) :(
        queryDatabase().flatMap(it -> {
            reactiveRedisOperation.opsForValue().set("tango", it, Duration.ofSeconds(3600)).then(Mono.just(it)); 
        })})
    );
}
```

#### UPDATE:

I don't have much experience with `Mono`. The answer that I pointed explain it:

> ... computation was already triggered at the point when we start composing our `Mono` types.  To prevent unwanted computations we can wrap our future into a defered evaluation:
>
> ... is trapped in a lazy supplier and is scheduled for execution only when it will be requested.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either. It is still querying DB even if value is present in Redis.

Comment: @nicholasnet Update: new approach

Comment: I have tried that one too and it was not working. But now I try yours and it is working. Since I have tried so many thing I have lost track of it. But your given solution is working ... so I am good. Thank you very much for your help. But out of curiosity why we need `Mono.defer()` here?

Comment: @nicholasnet I added update, but explanation is in the answer the I pointed

Comment: yeah I noticed that later. I read the link it was good thank you very much for sharing it.